# cannot pickle 'generator' object created using yield key-word

Tags: python, generator, pickle, python-multiprocessing

As shown in the below posted code, I call `__yieldIterables()` to generate iterables according to what the list `self.__itersList` contains. At run time I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot pickle 'generator' object
```

Please let me know how to correct the below code in such a way that I can still convert the contents of `self.__itersList` to iterables that can be passed to the `self.run()`

**code**:

```
def postTask(self):
    arg0 = self.getDistancesModel().getFieldCoordinatesAsTextInWKTEPSG25832()
    self.__itersList.append(self.getDistancesModel().getNZCCCenterPointsAsString())
    self.__itersList.append(self.getDistancesModel().getZCCCenterPointsAsString())
    self.__itersList.append(self.getDistancesModel().getNoDataCCenterPointsAsString())
    
    with Pool(processes=self.__processesCount,initializer=self.initPool,initargs=(arg0,)) as DistancesRecordsPool.pool:
        self.__iterables = self.__yieldIterables()
        self.__chunkSize = PoolUtils.getChunkSizeForLenOfIterables(lenOfIterablesList=len(self.__itersList),cpuCount=self.__cpuCount)
        for res in DistancesRecordsPool.pool.map(func=self.run,iterable=self.__iterables,chunksize=self.__chunkSize):
            self.__res.append(res)
    
    DistancesRecordsPool.pool.join()
    gPostgreSQLHelperObject.closeConnection()
    return self.__res

def __yieldIterables(self):
    for i in self.__itersList:
        yield i
```

Comment: Why does `__yieldIterables` even exist? Why not just use `self.__itersList` directly?

Comment: @user2357112 oh, i did not notice that..sorry it is my mistake. however, can you tell me why yield key word does not work as suppose to be though??

Comment: Pool won't work with generators

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest thanks. but can you please correct the above code so it works?i mean, what if i want to use yield, how that is possible